# Cannot resolve method getException() at JSP and Servlets

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea, servlets

I have an issue with JSP file when i try to use "pageContext" in scritplet.

```
<%
String message = pageContext.getException().getMessage();
String exception = pageContext.getException().getClass().toString();%>
```

IDEA drops an error: "Cannot resolve method 'getException()'" but i tried this code in eclipse IDE too and everything was OK.

In my pom.xml file i have all servlets dependencies in.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: first of all, PageContext is a part of jsp-api (you need to add this dependency as well), at second, if memory serves me right Idea CE does not support JSP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need **jsp-api** dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

[image: proof]

Comment: IDEA says: "javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:2.2' not found "

Comment: Make sure to reload Maven project, as you can see from the edited answer screenshot, it works fine.